# Asynchronously monitor value passed byRef

Tags: vba, excel, pointers, asynchronous

I have created a class in VBA which is designed to monitor a variable until it changes. The class runs asynchronously; a Windows Timer API calls the `Tick` method every second or so - like `Application.OnTime`

```
Option Explicit

Public Event Tick()
Public Event Complete()

Private Type tTimer
    tickFrequency As Double                      'in seconds
    conditionMet As Boolean
End Type

Private this As tTimer

Public Sub await(ByRef waitUntil As Boolean, Optional ByVal tickFrequency As Double = 1)
    this.conditionMet = waitUntil 'only creates a copy, doesn't point to the same variable
    startTicking tickFrequency, Me
End Sub

Public Sub Tick()
    If this.conditionMet Then  'If initially False then will never be updated to True
        stopTicking
        RaiseEvent Complete
    Else
        RaiseEvent Tick
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    stopTicking
End Sub
```

Called like

```
Dim someCondition As Boolean
'evaluate condition
await someCondition, 0.5 'check back every half a second
'continue other processes which may alter the value of someCondition
```

The idea was to pass the condition `byRef`, so that changes could be monitored every tick. Meanwhile other code running asynchronously (such as a button on a worksheet) could edit the value of the variable as much as necessary.

I can think of a few workarounds;

- Exposing `waitUntil` as a public variable of the class, so that caller code can write to it directly
- Wrapping the condition in an object as these are always passed around as pointers (never copied)

However both of these require extra steps on the caller-side which I don't want.

I wonder whether I could do some trickery with `VarPtr` - if I understand correctly this returns an address in memory of the variable passed `byRef`. So by saving a copy of that address in my class I can look up the variable at that location whenever I need. However I don't know how to do this and can't phrase the question succinctly enough to search!

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.thevbzone.com/secrets.htm) is a bit of help.

Answer (score 0):

Well one way is, as I mentioned, to use the `VarPtr` function to lookup the value. The CopyMemory Api method moves the value in the lookup address to a new variable.

```
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (dest As _
    Any, source As Any, ByVal bytes As Long)

' read a value of any type from memory

Function Peek(ByVal address As Long, ByVal ValueType As VbVarType) As Variant
    Select Case ValueType
        Case vbByte
            Dim valueB As Byte
            CopyMemory valueB, ByVal address, 1
            Peek = valueB
        Case vbInteger
            Dim valueI As Integer
            CopyMemory valueI, ByVal address, 2
            Peek = valueI
        Case vbBoolean
            Dim valueBool As Boolean
            CopyMemory valueBool, ByVal address, 2
            Peek = valueBool
        Case vbLong
            Dim valueL As Long
            CopyMemory valueL, ByVal address, 4
            Peek = valueL
        Case vbSingle
            Dim valueS As Single
            CopyMemory valueS, ByVal address, 4
            Peek = valueS
        Case vbDouble
            Dim valueD As Double
            CopyMemory valueD, ByVal address, 8
            Peek = valueD
        Case vbCurrency
            Dim valueC As Currency
            CopyMemory valueC, ByVal address, 8
            Peek = valueC
        Case vbDate
            Dim valueDate As Date
            CopyMemory valueDate, ByVal address, 8
            Peek = valueDate
        Case vbVariant
            ' in this case we don't need an intermediate variable
            CopyMemory Peek, ByVal address, 16
        Case Else
            Err.Raise 1001, , "Unsupported data type"
    End Select

End Function
```

This can then be used like

```
Public Sub await(ByRef waitUntil As Boolean, Optional ByVal tickFrequency As Double = 1)
    this.conditionAddress= VarPtr(waitUntil) 'only creates a copy, doesn't point to the same variable
    startTicking tickFrequency, Me
End Sub


Public Sub Tick()
    If Peek(this.conditionAddress, vbBoolean) Then  'If initially False then will never be updated to True
        stopTicking
        RaiseEvent Complete
    Else
        RaiseEvent Tick
    End If
End Sub
```

to check the variable's value every `Tick`

Comment: It should be noted that this method is inherently quite dangerous. If the memory for the variable passed in `waitUntil` is deallocated (i.e. it goes out of scope), you risk either reading trash memory and getting the wrong result (best case), or an access violation (worst case). Since the lifetime of an object is determined by its reference count, this will only be safe if you guarantee that the lifespan of the object does not exceed the scope of the passed parameter.